# How to access an Object's methods within a foreach loop?

Tags: java, foreach

I have the following code:

```
for(Object o : allObjects) {
    o.Walk();
}
```

The `allObjects` list contains what I think are objectreferences when printed to the console ("Animal@f769314").

The error I get states that the method `Walk()` could not be found.

Why does this happen? Usually I can simply use the " . " to access methods within an object.
Does this error occur because I never did something like `o = new o()` inside of the loop? Creating a new object shouldn't be the right solution.

I don't know how I could make a minimal reproducible example for this, but here's a little more information.

Inside the API I use, theres a method getObjectsInRange():

> protected  java.util.List getObjectsInRange(int radius,
>                                                     java.lang.Class cls)
>
> Return all objects within range 'radius' around this object. An object
>   is within range if the distance between its centre and this object's
>   centre is less than or equal to 'radius'.
>
> Parameters: radius - Radius of the circle (in cells)
>
> cls - Class of objects to look for (passing 'null' will find all
>   objects).
>
> Returns: List of objects of the given class type within the given
>   radius.

All the Objects in the radius inherit from a class `Moveables` which contains the `Walk()` method.

Comment: `java.lang.Object` has no `Walk` method! BTW: java naming conventions says that methods should start with lower case character

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: @Jens its in a program called Greenfoot. If you'd install it, here's the project file (just open it.) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ciSA2xWIt4rod4H1sHPQtQJ8sI0JoRDm)

Comment: no i do not install anything. An [mcve] shold always provided in the question on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.Object` has no `Walk` method!

I guess you have a `List<MyObject> allObjects` where `MyObject` has a `Walk`method. So you code must looks like

```
for(MyObject o : allObjects) {
    o.Walk();
}
```

BTW: java naming conventions says that methods should start with lower case character

Comment: The List not only contains `MyObject`, but also other classes which all have the Walk() method. Is there any way to implement that? Or should I just do the foreach loop for every class?

Comment: @hjknvcaesdbuihjase Do the classes implements an interface or have a common base class which defines the walk method? If not it can make sence to intoduce an abstract base class or interface which is implemented by all the classes

Comment: I just tried to use a base class `Moveables` for all moveable classes, but now the problem is that the method I use to get all the Objects in a list only returns a list of type Object. So it says: "java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Moveables".

Comment: @hjknvcaesdbuihjase Have you defined your list as `List<Moveables>` ?

Comment: I did not create the list myself, instead I used the API's method (see question edit)

Comment: @hjknvcaesdbuihjase Maybe you should take a look [here](https://www.greenfoot.org/topics/1637)

Answer (score 0):

The pure `Object` in Java has no method called `Walk()`. You must cast it to your required object, and check if it's a valid instance using `instanceof` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your all objects are in List, your code should like this.
You need to instanciate objects with 'new' while adding to list. And then when you foreach loop, you should be able to access other methods in objects.

Note:- make sure you dont mistakenly use the 'Object' class with capital 'O' in your foreloop.

```
List<object> m = new ArrayList<object>();
m.add(new object());
m.add(new object());
for(object t:m){
   object.walk();
```

Comment: Class names in java should start with upper case charaker! and call an class `object` is very bad practice

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't want it to be get confused with universal Object class if you know what I mean.